# Next Entry with only the url_title

Tags: channel-images, next-prev

I am having trouble finding a way to get the next entry from an article. With the way that my URI is set up.

For example, I have the URL http ://www.***.com/learn/[channel]/[url_title]. I use the exp:channel:entries tag with the channel parameter set to segment_2 and the url_title parameter set to segment_3(I understand that segment_2 is not really needed to get the results I am after). This displays the article I requested. However, the exp:next_entry tag will not work unless the actual channel is in segment_1.

I have tried other plugins such as [Advanced Prev Next Entry](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/advanced-prev-next-entry), but I have requirements that these don't meet, such as compatibility with Channel Images.

My ultimate goal is to be able to reproduce an experience [like this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/30/medium-style-page-transition/?codekitCB=408043078.038843).

Any help on how to find the next entry would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the built in Pagination?

{exp:channel:entries channel="article" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="1" paginate="bottom" }
    {title}
{article_details..etc}
    {paginate}
        {if next_page}
            Next Page
        {/if}
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Good thought, except that I would need access to a couple of the channel fields from the next entry such as Title and Channel Images.